# Why does LayerNorm use a biased standard deviation estimator?

Tags: pytorch, batch-normalization

The LayerNorm computation in the original paper [Layer Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450.pdf) uses a biased estimator of standard deviation (see equation 3 below). Why does it use a biased estimator instead of an unbiased estimator?

[image: Layer Norm]

Comment: I don't think there is a good unbiased estimator of the standard deviation. See the discussion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation you need to assume e.g. that the distribution is normal to do that.

Besides, we are not trying to estimate anything. We just want to normalize the vector.